# weird behaviour with list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is a simple code that performs operations on lists:

```
>>> a = [0] * 5
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> a[0] = 5
>>> a
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

For now, nothing abnormal.

Now, I try to do the same with a list of dictionaries instead of a list of integers:

```
>>> a = [{}] * 5
>>> a
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
>>> a[0]['b'] = 4
>>> a
[{'b': 4}, {'b': 4}, {'b': 4}, {'b': 4}, {'b': 4}]
>>>
```

I don't understand why all elements of my list are modified...

Can anyone tell me why? And also provide a workaround?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8240157/566644) answer for an in-depth explanation of this behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value changing at multiple positions in a list of list when trying to change at one place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240054/value-changing-at-multiple-positions-in-a-list-of-list-when-trying-to-change-at)

Answer (score 9):

This is not weird.

---

Workaround:

```
a = [{} for i in xrange(5)]
```

---

`[…] * 5` creates one `…` and a list of five pointers to this `…`.

`0` is an immutable integer. You cannot modify it, you can just replace it with another integer (such as `a[0] = 5`). Then it is a different integer.

`{}` is a mutable dictionary. You are modifying it: `a[0]['b'] = 4`. It is always the same dictionary.

Comment: +1 This creates a list of 5 dictionaries, rather than a list of 5 references to a dictionary.  Why?  Guido made it that way!  Dictionaries are accessed by reference.

Comment: The mutability has nothing to do with it. `a[0] = {'b': 4}` would have worked perfectly well; the key is that the original code makes no attempt to replace the dictionary.

Comment: -1: It's not a "workaround".  It's "correct use of mutable objects".

Comment: Do I have to close post? If yes how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a = map([].append, {} for i in xrange(3))
```