# Weird Python behavior

Tags: python

I wrote a code in python which looks like:

```
maplist=[{}]*11
mylist=[0]*11
maplist[0]['this']=1
print maplist
```

When I print maplist the output is :

```
[{'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}, {'this': 1}]
```

Expected is:

```
[{'this': 1}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

rather than only the first element of the list should have this key in the map. What is causing this problem?

Comment: It's amazing how often we get a subtle variation on the same question... in addition to marking things as duplicates, I'm starting to feel like we need to have a way to create a per-tag FAQ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do the following:

```
maplist=[{}]*11
```

you end up with eleven references to the same dictionary. This means that when you modify one dictionary, they all appear to change.

To fix, replace that line with:

```
maplist=[{} for in xrange(11)]
```

Note that, since `0` is a scalar, the next line is fine as it is:

```
mylist=[0]*11
```

Comment: Ohh came across this for the first time. Is there any specific reason why python do so , is it useful someehere?

Comment: @Piyush It is just a consequence of the way the * operator works on lists. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8240157/566644) for a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you type

```
maplist=[{}]*11
```

You're creating a list of 11 references to the same `dict`. Only one dictionary gets created.

To create 11 separate dictionaries you can do something like this:

```
>>> maplist = [{} for i in range(11)]
>>> maplist[0]['this'] = 1
>>> maplist
[{'this': 1}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```